# Updating a column in every row occurence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding ORACLE SQL.
What I am trying to do is updating the value in a column based on its row value

So, my table is something like this,

```
NAME   VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3 SOURCEVAL RESULT
HEAD2       0      1      0       30       0
HEAD2       1      0      1       30       0
HEAD2       1      1      1       30       0
```

And this is my SQL

```
 update testa set result = (select (testa.value1*testa.sourceval)+(testa.value2*testa.sourceval)+(testa.value3*testa.sourceval) from testa)
```

Basically I want to update the column result based on the data in each row.
my desired result would be

```
First HEAD2 Result = 30,
Second HEAD2 Result = 60,
Third HEAD2 Result = 90
```

Please help me I keep getting "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" Error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
update testa
set result = (value1*sourceval) + (value2*sourceval) + (value3*sourceval)
```

No need for a subquery in this case.  The error you're getting is because you're subquery returns more than a single row.

Alternatively, this would also work:

```
update testa
set result = (value1+value2+value3)*sourceval
```